# how do I limit user's input in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim Number_of_courses As Integer

Number_of_courses = TextBox.Text
Number_of_courses > 0 and Number_of_courses < 8
```

I wish to limit the user's input from 1 to 8

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.rangevalidator?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Assuming this is a winforms project, you could use a numeric spin edit and set the min/max properties as required

Comment: OP, do like suggested by Hursey. Use the right controls for the job and don't make life difficult when it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming WinForms...

Use [Integer.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-5.0#System_Int32_TryParse_System_String_System_Int32__) to convert the STRING in your TextBox to an Integer.  Then you can do the checks on it to make sure it's within range:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Number_of_courses As Integer

    If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, Number_of_courses) Then
        If Number_of_courses > 0 And Number_of_courses < 8 Then
            ' ... do something with "Number_of_courses" in here ...
            MessageBox.Show("Number_of_courses = " & Number_of_courses)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Number of Courses.  Please enter a valid integer greater than zero and less then eight.")
        End If
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Number of Courses.  Please enter a valid integer.")
    End If
End Sub
```